# Upload Somente de Imagens

Tags: html5

Como fazer upload somente de imagens(`.png` e `.jpeg`)? Não permitir a escolha de outro tipo de arquivo.

Estou usando conforme abaixo:

```html
 <input type="file" name="arquivos" class="btn btn-success" multiple/>
```

Na hora da seleção das fotos não quero permitir a escolha de outros tipos de arquivos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Coloque isso na tag `<input>`

```
<input type="file" name="arquivos" class="btn btn-success"  accept="image/png, image/jpeg"  multiple />
```

Agora o botão irá aceitar somente arquivos do tipo imagem com extensão .jpeg e .png (nem se quer irá mostrar outras opções na área de seleção de arquivos)

Adicione ao `<form>` `onsubmit="Checkfiles(this)"` e coloque um `id` em seu `input`.

usando em conjunto um código javascript:

```
function Checkfiles(){
    var fup = document.getElementById('filename');
    var fileName = fup.value;
    var ext = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);

    if(ext =="jpeg" || ext=="png"){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Obrigado! Funcionou, porem, na tela de seleção de arquivos, na opção de mudar o tipo de arquivo, permite a mudança para "Todos os Arquivos" dessa forma é possível selecionar qualquer arquivo. Existe alguma forma de bloquear isso??

Comment: Adicione: `accept="image/png, image/jpeg"` no `input` de da tela de seleção de arquivos.

Comment: Já adicionei mas como eu disse: permite a mudança para "Todos os Arquivos" , teria como bloquear isso??

Comment: Estou usando esse: <input type="file" name="arquivos" class="btn btn-success"  accept="image/png, image/jpeg"  multiple />

Comment: coloque o código da `opção de mudar o tipo de arquivo`

Comment: Não há código para mudar o tipo de arquivo. Me refiro quando clicamos no input que abri a tela de seleção para escolher os arquivos conforme link (http://www.tickimg.com.br/uploads/_exemplo.png)

Comment: Não confio muito em usar a validação desta maneira, pois o usuário que conheça HTML pode remover esta configuração e fazer o upload de qualquer arquivo. Existe maneiras de fazer esta validação via PHP que é bem mais seguro( se você estiver usando esta linguagem).

Comment: A onde que eu coloco o onsubmit="Checkfiles(this)" ?  
No form?

Answer (score 1):

Pra quem ainda estiver pesquisando sobre isso, fiz de uma outra forma que talvez tbm possa ajudar.
obs: files seria o input.

```
const validTypes = ['png', 'PNG', 'jpg', 'JPG', 'jpeg', 'JPEG', 'pdf', 'PDF']

const valid = validTypes.filter(e=>{ if(files[0].name.includes(e)) return e })

if (!files[0].name.includes(valid[0])) {
    alert('Por favor insira o imagens nos formatos JPG, PNG e PDF')
    return
}
```

`